# How to receive large response from azure http trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, httpresponse

My application will call a `http trigger` to read a blob file.

I was able to receive the response from my http trigger when the file size is small (around 30MB). When the file size is around 160MB then my application  is receiving empty response.

Facing this issue is only when the Http trigger is deployed in azure environment. When run the http trigger from my local machine and call local http trigger in my app its working fine.

Calling App

```
string WebAddress = "https://MyfunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/api/Report";
//string WebAddress = "http://localhost:7071/api/FIComparisonReport";
string WebServiceUri = string.Format("{0}?groupcode={1}&domicile={2}&legalstructure={3}",
                WebAddress,
                Uri.EscapeDataString(groupCode),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(domicile),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(legalStructure));

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(WebServiceUri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Timeout = 360000;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string responseText = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
{
    responseText = reader.ReadToEnd(); // empty for large files
}
```

Http trigger

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
//read blob to stream 
 MemoryStream resultSets = myfunc();
 var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(resultSets.GetBuffer())
            };

response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return response;
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: tell us more about your use case, perhaps we can suggest a slightly different architecture, normally you wouldnt want to return that much data via http

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I'm trying to read the json file from blob storage in display it in asp.net gridview.

Comment: You need to look at signalr

Comment: @mjwills I don't think this is a duplicate. This question relates to the response and has a different root cause from the related request issue that was posted.

Comment: I can't write up an actual answer but this link was how I solved the issue: https://debuggers.domains/post/azure-functions-large-response/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response size is limited to 100 MB max.

> the runtime limit, which was just bumped up to 100MB.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1063#issuecomment-288818131

This talks about HTTP requests but I believe the same limit is true for responses.

Comment: But how it is working when the http trigger is hosted in my local machine

Comment: Because your local machine isn't Azure.

Comment: exactly. If you host the functions runtime yourself (which is what happens when you run locally even for debugging), there are different limits (or often none at all) in place. As Azure is a shared and fully managed environment, certain limits need to be put in place

Comment: I return much larger responses from Azure Functions on even consumption plans. I think this is a memory limitation, not a response limitation.